# Is it useful to store a data frame that does not perform actions but it will be used by others that do actions in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What happens when I cache a data frame in memory that will not perform actions but will be used by other data frames that will perform actions?

```
val sparkS: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

val  dataFrameA : DataFrame  = sparkS.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv(pathA)
      .filter( condition ).cache()



val  dataFrameB : DataFrame  = sparkS.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv(pathB)

val  dataFrameC : DataFrame  = sparkS.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv(pathC)


val resultB =  dataFrameB.crossJoin(dataFrameA)
resultB.count()
resultB.show()

val resutC =  dataFrameC.crossJoin(dataFrameA)
resutC.count()
resutC.show()
```

Will it cache the data frame A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be helpful to cache `dataFrameA` since it's output is used in multiple places.

But to take a step back, even if you don't call a method on `dataFrameA`, an action can still be performed on it. When you write Spark code, you're providing Spark with a set of "transformations" that eventually end in an "action". Spark will then take the steps of the transformations / actions you provide and translate that into an execution plan. It is not important on which objects you call which methods, because as long as the data is used in a computation, it will be present in the execution plan.

If you want to see how Spark is creating the execution plan, you can use the `explain()` method on your result DataFrame.

Comment: Make sense, I'm going to check the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you call `cache`, it does cache the Dataframe.

Comment: As far as I know, a data frame will be cached until it invokes a Spark action, the dataFrameA never performs a Spark action, but it is being used by others that are performing Spark actions, like show and count.